# How to find out the gap left between bottom of the screen and the bottom-most HTML content?

Tags: javascript, html

Using JavaScript, How do I find out, how much gap is left after bottom most element, be it text, image, canvas or a video ends.

I want to calculate, how much empty space I have at the bottom of the HTML page.

A webkit-only solution would work well. I am only concentrating on iOS 5.0 +

**UPDATE**

I am working on an iOS app, I want to resize a webview, a web browser control that holds the HTML page, I woul like to reset It's height so that, lot of whitespace is not left at the bottom, for which I want to know some JS coe that I can run and its result would give me, the height I have to reduce from the webview.

Comment: I think this simple calculation will work.You can find the height of the parent container then ur container height.If u subtrat ur container value from ur parent container u will get the value..If i was misunderstood ur question pleas add any example code here

Answer (score 1):

Since you didnt provide an example code, i did an example for myself:

Javascript:

```
   var height = 0;    
   var allBoxes = [].slice.call(doc.querySelectorAll('.TestKenjin'));  
   var heightDisplay = (window.innerHeight > 0) ? window.innerHeight : screen.height;

   for(var i=0; i < allBoxes.length; i++)  {
     height += allBoxes[i].clientHeight;
   }

   alert(heightDisplay-height);
```

JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/olucas/6/edit

Answer (score 1):

This javascript will `alert` the height between the bottom of the `html` element and the bottom of the page.

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8hneq/26/) of it.

```
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

var documentHeight = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
     html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );

var htmlHeight = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].offsetHeight;

alert(documentHeight - htmlHeight);
```